# Scaling factor of the base and any cross section area in tetrahedron.

Tags: geometry, platonic-solids

I'm given that the scaling factor of the areas between base and any cross section parallel to the base in a tetrahedron is $(\frac{H-h}{H})^2$, where $H$ is the height of the tetrahedron and $h$ is the height from base to the cross section.

I don't understand this, could someone help me to visualize this?

Thank you.

Comment: I disagree, this factor should be squared.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Edited.

Comment: The factor under the square equals $1$ for $h=0$ and $0$ for $h=H$, and grows linearly in between, like the side of the section. The square is for the area.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a drawing:

[image]

Is this helping?